# Using logic in Regex

Tags: regex

I would like to extract data from the following configuration using Regex:

```
Eth 1/1/1       abc-p01.be01    up       10G      full     -
Eth 1/1/2                       down     0        full     A    1    -
Eth 1/1/3                       down     0        full     A    1    -
Eth 1/1/4       abc-02.be01     up       10G      full     -
Eth 1/1/14      dcba-08.fa01    up       10G      full     -
```

I've come this far:

```
(?P<port>Eth [\/\w\d\-]+)\s+[\w\d\-.]+\s+(?P<status>[up]+)\s+(?<speed>[\d\w]+)
```

Which gave me this result (https://regex101.com):

[image: None]

This is exactly what I want but it only works if the status is up. Is it possible to also match the down status (and with that the 0 speed) in the same regular expression? I've read about using logical operators in Regex (|) but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the pattern with an optional part as there is no value before "down", and then match either up or down in the named group status.

Note that `\w` also matches `\d` and if you put the hyphen at the end of the character class you don't have to escape it.

```
(?P<port>Eth [\/\w-]+)\s+(?:[\w.-]+\s+)?(?P<status>down|up)\s+(?<speed>\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CFflKV/1)